# Finding the sum of $\cos45°$ + $i\cos135°$ + ... + $i^{n}\cos(45+90n)°$ + ... + $i^{40}\cos3645°$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

My question is as follows: If $i^{2}$ = -1, find the value of $$\cos45° + i\cos135° + \ ...\ + i^{n}\cos(45+90n)° + \ ...\ + i^{40}\cos3645°$$ without the aid of a calculator. In terms of my attempts at the problem, I have begun by noticing that $$\cos(180°+x) = \cos180°\cos x - \sin180°\sin x = -\cos x,$$ and so  $$\cos45° = i^{2}\cos225° = i^{4}\cos315° = \ ... \  = i^{40}\cos3645°.$$ How do I simplify this summation with this information in mind? I do not have any idea how to do so *efficiently*. Many thanks.

Comment: $\cos(\alpha+90^\circ)=-\sin \alpha$ and Euler formula (perhaps).

Comment: Write down the first few terms. say the first $8$, though that's overkill, and everything may become clear. Note that $i^3=-i$.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859644/a-sum-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-qn-sinn-alpha  and 
 
See Article $#76$  of  https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobsuoft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the cosines and the powers of $i$ recur with period $4$, so you only need to compute the first four terms.  There are eleven of the first and ten of each subsequent.  So $$\cos 45^\circ=\frac {\sqrt 2}2\\
i\cos 135^\circ=-i\frac {\sqrt 2}2\\
i^2\cos 225^\circ=\frac {\sqrt 2}2\\
i^3\cos 315^\circ=-i\frac {\sqrt 2}2$$ and in fact we have repetition with period $2$ because the $i^2$ cancels with the change of sign of the cosine, so you sum is $21 \frac {\sqrt 2}2-20i\frac {\sqrt 2}2$

Answer (score 0):

As the principal value of  $i$ is $e^{i90^\circ}$ and $e^{i180^\circ}=-1,$ using  [Euler Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t) for any integer $r,$

$$i^r\{\cos(90^\circ r+45^\circ)+i\sin(90^\circ r+45^\circ)\}=(e^{ i90^\circ})^r e^{i(90^\circ r+45^\circ)}=e^{i45^\circ}(-1)^r$$

$$i^r\{\cos(90^\circ r+45^\circ)-i\sin(90^\circ r+45^\circ)\}=e^{r i90^\circ}\cdot e^{-i(90^\circ r+45^\circ)}=-e^{-i45^\circ}$$

$$\implies2\sum_{r=0}^{2n}i^r\cos(90^\circ r+45^\circ)=e^{i45^\circ}(-1)^0+(2n+1)(-e^{-i45^\circ})=?$$

Now use Euler Formula to find  $e^{\pm i45^\circ}=\dfrac{1\pm i}{\sqrt2}$